# db access via interactive tags map

Tags: database, tags, mapping

I want to create an interactive tags map, kinda like 'visual thesaurus' (http://www.visualthesaurus.com/), and use it as an a access portal to my DB (display tagged data in a separate area), what do you think would be the best technology to use?

I need something that would be SEO friendly of course, easy to use (user wise), and easy to program...

Any thoughts?

tnx
Liat.

Answer (score 0):

you talking about the Graph display?

http://www.jayday.org/thesaurus.jpg